# IEnumerable Model Object into Array

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I am learning C# and dotnet core as I want to move away from PHP for my web apps. I am having a specific problem here and I can't get my head around it.

I will show you all the code below, but here is a summary of what I want to achieve: I am getting a table from SQL database. I can display the table in full on my page using foreach loop. However when I am trying to convert the result into an array so I can access a specific item from the returned table I get into all sorts of errors.

By the way I was using this tutorial to supplement my Udemy learning course:
https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/existing-db.html

Might be worth mentioning that I was reverse engineering the Models from existing database (as it is in the linked tutorial above)

Here are my files, I'll explain errors below:

Model:

```
namespace ASPNET_Core_1_0.Models
{
    public partial class Graph
    {
        public int AutoId { get; set; }
        public int Numbers { get; set; }
    }

}
```

ModelContext:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;

namespace ASPNET_Core_1_0.Models
{
    public partial class GraphsContext : DbContext
    {
        public virtual DbSet<Graph> Graph { get; set; }


        public GraphsContext(DbContextOptions<GraphsContext> options)
            : base(options)
        { }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Graph>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.AutoId)
                    .HasName("PK_Blog");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using ASPNET_Core_1_0.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

// For more information on enabling MVC for empty projects, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860

namespace ASPNET_Core_1_0.Controllers
{
    public class GraphsController : Controller
    {
        private GraphsContext _context;

        public GraphsController(GraphsContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(_context.Graph.ToArray());
        }

        public IActionResult GraphJ()
        {
            var graphs = _context.Graph.FromSql("SELECT * FROM dbo.Graph").ToList();
            ViewBag.YourHtml = graphs;

            return View(_context.Graph.ToList());
        }

    }
}
```

In MS tutorial the Index view used ToList() method:

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_context.Graph.ToList());
    }
```

I changed it to ToArray() in hope it will behave like one :/

Index View

```
@model IEnumerable<ASPNET_Core_1_0.Models.Graph>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Graphs";
}

<h2>Graphs</h2>



<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Numbers</th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AutoId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Numbers)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>

@{ 

    // int[] arr = Model.ToArray();

    // int[] array = Model.Cast<int>().ToArray();
    // int somenumber = array[5];
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        @Html.DisplayForModel(Model)
        <br />

    </div>
</div>
```

**The problem:**

If you look at my index view, there are three commented out lines where I was trying to cast the Model object to array so I could access each item in the returned table independently.

Upon running the project I am getting an error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
>   'ASPNET_Core_1_0.Models.Graph' to type 'System.Int32'.

**Question:**
How can I get Model object into an array so I can display specific item from the table instead of the whole table.

Say I want to return Value field for ID 4?

I understand this most likely is a rookie question, but I am having real trouble getting or even understanding the answers I see online.

**Table data**

My table data is simple two column key -> value pair. ID number and corresponding value.

```
ID Value
1  10
2  20
3  30
4  40
5  50
```

ect

**Research**

[Best way to convert IList or IEnumerable to Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268671/best-way-to-convert-ilist-or-ienumerable-to-array)

[Convert IEnumerable<int> to int[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570334/convert-ienumerableint-to-int)

[Error: "Cannot implicitly convert type"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22382601/error-cannot-implicitly-convert-type)

[C# - Cannot implicitly convert type List<Product> to List<IProduct>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640738/c-sharp-cannot-implicitly-convert-type-listproduct-to-listiproduct)

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_arrays.htm

https://www.dotnetperls.com/array

https://www.dotnetperls.com/list

[How can I find a specific element in a List<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854917/how-can-i-find-a-specific-element-in-a-listt)

[Getting an item in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216438/getting-an-item-in-a-list)

[Getting a list item by index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15456845/getting-a-list-item-by-index)

[Get array item based on index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620648/get-array-item-based-on-index)

Comment: Which line of code is throwing the exception?

Comment: `int[] array = Model.Cast<int>().ToArray();` the middle line of the commented out lines in the view

Comment: It appears that you're trying to cast a `Graph` object to `int`, or whatever is in the `Graph` property of your model to `int`  Is that possible?

Comment: A `Graph` is not an `int`.  It's an object.  Which `int` *from* that object are you trying to use?

Comment: This is what I am trying to get my head around. The graph object is just the table from the database? Or am I completely on the wrong track here

Comment: It's either the table from the database, or a tuple from that table in the database.  Neither will cast to an `int`.  To get an `int` you need to refer to a column or field in your `Graph` object that corresponds to an `int`.

Comment: Hey Robert, thanks it just shows that I do not understand what I am dealing with here.

Comment: Well, you need to think carefully about what you are doing, and specify what it is that you want to do (your intent) in your code.  I'm not sure copy/paste programming is going to work here.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I am trying to learn. At the moment the copying and pasting code from different tutorials is all I can do. I do struggle with understanding some basic concepts, but the best way for me to learn is by trying. Once I fiddle with code I can move to trying to build something myself. As you can see by the way I am not asking anyone here for help with my work project (OMG help me with X or my boss is going to kill me) but with understanding - however basic - concepts.

Comment: If you want to display a specific object, it should be filtered in the controller (or better in the database) and the view should receive only that object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an array of `Graph` objects, not an array if `int`s.  If all you want is the array of `Numbers` values from those graphs, you can select it:

```
int[] array = Model.Select(g => g.Numbers).ToArray()
```

Or, to get a specific number from the array you already have:

```
int value = Model.ToArray()[0].Numbers
```

A `Graph` is more than just an `int`.  It's an object which *contains* `int`s.

Comment: I am just putting this in and will report back in a sec! In any case thank you for lightning fast response.

Comment: Hey David, I have put the `int value = Model.ToArray()[0].Numbers;` in the view and then tried to output it with `@Html.DisplayText(value.ToString());` - no errors this time, however nothing displays.

Comment: @PawelKosi: I don't think `Html.DisplayText()` does what you expect it to do.  What happens if you just emit `@value` to the page?

Comment: Yes! Thank you for taking time to help a learner. With this I can speed up my learning, now I know where there are blatant holes in my understanding. Accepted answer and +1

Answer (score 0):

Your model is type of `IEnumerable<ASPNET_Core_1_0.Models.Graph>` so you cannot parse it to `int` - this is the root cause of exception.

To display specific value from an array you can write:

```
@{
    int specificItemValue = Model[5].Numbers;
}
```

Comment: Let me give this a go and I will report back.